# How do I load a nib from a secondary process?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a process spawned with NSTask that needs to display a window. I started out just writing all the UI code by hand, but this has become a pain.

So, I created a new class with a xib, `MyWindowController`. I want to load up an instance of this controller in secondary process and have all the IBOutlets and whatnot work properly.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
// Get the bundle for the main application (not the subprocess).The executable lives in Contents/Helpers, so look two dirs up from its path for the main app bundle root.
NSArray *executablePathComponents = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] executableURL] pathComponents];
NSIndexSet *indexOfEveryComponentExceptLastTwo = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [executablePathComponents count] - 2)];
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[executablePathComponents objectsAtIndexes:indexOfEveryComponentExceptLastTwo]]];

// Load the controller nib.
NSNib *windowControllerNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyWindowController" bundle:myBundle];
MyWindowController *windowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] init];
NSArray *topLevelObjects = nil;
[windowControllerNib instantiateNibWithOwner:windowController topLevelObjects:topLevelObjects];
```

This gives me an instance of the window controller and it displays the window from the nib on screen, so this appears to work. BUT, `instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects` is deprecated in favor of instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects.

Using the non-deprecated method results in an exception: "-`[NSNib instantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10291ab1"

At the very least I'd like to not use the deprecated method. But maybe there is a better way  to approach this whole thing?

Comment: Would you check your typing? Above it says "instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects is deprecated in favor of instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects".

Comment: Off hand, it looks like you're doing everything right except you should pass a pointer to your NSArray* instead of the NSArray* value itself. In other words, change `topLevelObjects:topLevelObjects` to `topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects`.